# How to host an ASP.NET Core web application as a sub-application to a .NET Framework application in IISExpress

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis, iis-express

I have an existing .NET Framework MVC site in Visual Studio configured to use IISExpress at https://localhost:44330.

I would like to add a new ASP.NET Core application as a sub-application under https://localhost:44330/identity.

I’ve added the new site and configured the URL to be https://localhost:44330/identity which works as expected when debugging in Visual Studio. The existing site also continues to work when debugging in Visual Studio. What doesn’t work is running both at the same time. How can I have both sites running at once?

Note: In production an Azure Application Gateways routes request for `\identity` to a separate backend pool.

Comment: each site run on a different process so this means you want 2 different processes to listen on one same port which is just impossible.

Comment: ASP.NET 4.x and ASP.NET Core web apps must run in separate application pools, but IIS Express is a single process web server without application pools, so what you wished cannot be achieved. Please switch to full IIS.